# Obtaining current working directory in a UNIX script

Tags: unix

Going through a UNIX shell script, I noticed that the path to the current working directory is being obtained using the following

```
BASE_DIR=$( readlink -e `dirname $0` )
```

the command 'pwd' also returns the same results. Is there a reason to use the above instead of pwd ?

Answer (score 0):

The above returns the location of the file being executed, not the pwd, which can differ.